# '<?php' tag is echoed with certain commands in Laravel, including JSON responses

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

** EDIT **

Found problem, I had an empty route file with only the <?php tag. Everytime the app went to register all routes in the RouteServieProvider, it output the php tag.

Any time I run any laravel commands, the "<?php" tag accompanies every output. This means that in some cases, when my laravel app goes to return json for an ajax request, the json response text string includes <?php in front of it, making my json invalid. I just updated homebrew and I'm using zsh. I don't know how to go about debugging this issue.

```
❯ art tinker
<?phpPsy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 7.3.28 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>>
```

Json responses to browser:

```
<?php{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":5,...
```

I'm using:

macos 11.4
Homebrew 3.1.9
Laravel 8.

I'd also like to note, that not all php applications do this, laravel commands do, however composer does not.

** UPDATE **

Some commands create the issue and others don't.

```
❯ art optimize
<?phpConfiguration cache cleared!
<?phpConfiguration cached successfully!
Route cache cleared!
<?phpRoutes cached successfully!
Files cached successfully!
```

Comment: Does it only occur when you use that `art` alias? Or also when using `php artisan tinker`?

Comment: Search the project for any echo statements.

Comment: @brombeer it does also happen when I use `php artisan tinker`

Comment: @brombeer see update